How many $2\times4$ matrices have nonzero minors in a finite field?
A $2\times4$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&a_{1,3}&a_{1,4}\\
a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&a_{2,3}&a_{2,4}\end{bmatrix}$ has $6$ different $2\times2$ submatrices (the determinants of which, I believe, are called minors). Suppose we have a finite field with $q$ elements, $\Bbb F_q$. How many $2\times4$ matrices are there such that none of the $2\times2$ minors are $0$?
In other words, we want eight scalars $a_{1,1}\dots,a_{2,4}\in\Bbb F_q$ such that
$$a_{1,i}a_{2,j}\ne a_{2,i}a_{1,j}$$
for $i\ne j$ where $i,j\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.
One clear upper bound is $q^8$. Up to a factor of $(q^2-1)(q^2-q)$, this is the same as asking for $2$-dim subspaces of $(\Bbb F_q)^4$ that miss the subspace $0^2\times(\Bbb F_q)^2$ and permutations thereof.
Eventually I'd like to generalize this to other sizes. I'd also like to know what happens if we require both rows to add to $0$.
I asked this question to a friend who brought up the Weil conjectures and toric varieties, both of which I know almost nothing about. Does this really need tech like that?

Equivalently, you're counting ordered $4$-tuples of vectors in $(\mathbb F_q)^2$ that are pairwise linearly independent.  There are $q^2-1$ nonzero members of $(\mathbb F_q)^2$, and each $1$-dimensional subspace contains $q-1$ of them, so there are $q+1$ such subspaces.  There are $(q+1)!/(q-3)!$ permutations of these subspaces taken $4$ at a time, and in each subspace you have $q-1$ possible vectors, so your answer is
$$ \frac{(q+1)!}{(q-3)!}(q-1)^4 = (q+1) q (q-1)^5 (q-2) $$

Much simpler than anticipated! Thanks!

Do you have thoughts on the version where the rows add to 0? Perhaps there's some sort of symmetry among  the cases where they don't.

(Cont'd) Clearly not all $q^2$ possible sums of rows are equally likely, since this isn't a multiple of $q^2$. I'm willing to believe that the $(q-1)^2$ possibilities where the row sums are both nonzero are equally likely, but this isn't enough to solve.
